# MagicalRecord delete core data store when rebooting the application

Tags: xcode, core-data, magicalrecord

I don't know why but MagicalRecord delete my store every time I reboot the application, I saw in the documentation :

> When using the default sqlite data store with the DEBUG flag set, if you change your model without creating a new model version, Magical Record will delete the old store and create a new one automatically. No more uninstall/reinstall every time you make a change! ([see magicalRecord github page](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

Removed the DEBUG flag,Tried to create a new model version, MR is still deleting my store...

Help me please :-)

Comment: This may be stupid, but I can't find the aforementioned DEBUG flag. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug. Please add an [issue](https://github.com/magicalpanda/magicalrecord/issues) to the github repo. Or, if you need to get going faster, you can peek into the code, and comment out the line that checks to see if your model is compatible with your persistent store.

Comment: An issue is opened on their github account : https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/353#issuecomment-11776473